# How could i go back to poster frame when the videos are ended?

Tags: javascript

I use Videojs to pulish my videos for my site.  I tried to search many informations on Google for this question, but i still didn't find a good answer. I think that maybe you could help me out, thanks.

Comment: You need to provide the plugin`s link as well

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it, could you provide some examples to me?

Comment: I meant you need to provide the official link of the **videojs** plugin,so that ppl on SO can refer it to help you with your problem.